# ControllerDescriptor FindAction returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

controller:

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
}
```

method:

```
ControllerBase controllerToLinkTo = string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName)
                                        ? htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller
                                        : GetControllerByName(htmlHelper, controllerName);

var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, controllerToLinkTo);
var controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerToLinkTo.GetType());
ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor = controllerDescriptor.FindAction(controllerContext, actionName);
```

ActionDescriptor is null when an action has [Delete] attribute. Is there a way to get Action Name from controller context?

Comment: The same issue will happen with HttpPost (at least it does for me)

Comment: @AndrewBacker indeed, I had the same problem on my project with HttpPost, and the answer by Juan Carlos worked!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem in .net 4.5, because the FindAction method only search the get attributes. I resolved the problem adding a second search with the GetCanonicalActions method.

```
ControllerBase controllerToLinkTo = string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName)
                                                        ? htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller
                                                        : GetControllerByName(htmlHelper, controllerName);

var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, controllerToLinkTo);
var controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerToLinkTo.GetType());
var actionDescriptor = controllerDescriptor.FindAction(controllerContext, actionName);

//add the following lines
if (actionDescriptor == null)
{
    actionDescriptor = controllerDescriptor.GetCanonicalActions().FirstOrDefault(a => a.ActionName == actionName);
}
```

Note: I use the linq method FirstOrDefault, so rember add `using System.Linq`;

Comment: What I did to handle the same problem with HttpPost was to use GetCanonicalActions but in a more restrictive way (more suited to my problem), like this : GetCanonicalActions().SingleOrDefault(e => e.ActionName == actionName &&  e.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HttpPostAttribute), false).Length > 0);